# Why can't l chose much or far instead of quite?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, gerunds, quantifiers

I solved a problem in which l picked  wrong answer and the question is the part of text which has blank to be filled . Text is very long so l want to give a part of the text .

"I don't like reading financial  pages because they tend to be very long.l like reading arts pages  and l find that (quite) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

**[Quite](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/quite)** means "to a considerable extent or degree."

> This is quite interesting.

[**Much**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/much?s=t) can also mean "to a great extent or degree," and **[far](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/far?s=t)** can mean "much," but you can't always just replace one word with another.

We do not use "much" or "far" before adjectives in their positive forms (interesting, quick...) but only before their comparative forms (more interesting, quicker...) ([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/much_1)). So you can say:

> This is much *(or far)* more interesting.